# how to retrieve the array which is send from controller to the view through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am new in jquery and ajax. I am really cant figured it out how can i show the array result send from the controller from json_encode. 
Below is the code in controller:

**Controller**

```
            $totaldata['data'] = array('totalscore' =>$totalscore,'totalwicket' =>$totalwicket,'totalover' =>$totalover,'totalextra' =>$totalextra);

            $this->output->set_output(json_encode($totaldata));
```

**Jquery**

```
  $.ajax({
               url: 'xxxxxxxxx',
               type : 'POST',
               data:{
                        xxxx : arrayValue,
                        id    : matchid,
               },
               success: function(dataone){
                  //$('.addmatchsuccess').html(dataone).show();

                    //setTimeout(function() {location.reload() },3000);
               }
            });
```

**Problem**
I want to get each array value to be placed in a input field in view ...which i couldnt figured out still how it gonna work. Please any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: could you please post associated HTML too..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this worked for you.

```
success: function(dataone){
                  var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(dataone);
                  var totalscore = parsedJson.totalscore;
                  var totalwicket = parsedJson.totalwicket
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

> If the response is in the form of `string` then you need to parse it using `JSON.parse` else you can read `keys` from `object`(dataone)

Try this:

```
if (typeOf dataone === 'string') {
  myData = JSON.parse(dataone)['data'];
} else {
  myData = dataone['data'];
}
var totalscore = myData['totalscore'];;
var totalwicket = myData['totalwicket'];
var totalover = myData['totalover'];
var totalextra = myData['totalextra'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    success: function(dataone){
              var json_response= eval('('+response+')');
              var totalscore =json_response.totalscore
              var totalwicket =json_response.totalwicket
              var totalover = json_response.totalover
              var totalextra = json_response.totalextra
           }
```